# buttons do not appear with a recycle view

Tags: kivy

```
'''
Does not appear the buttons inside recycleview
'''

class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bx = RecycleBoxLayout(default_size=(None, dp(56)), default_size_hint=(1, None),
                                               size_hint=(1, None), orientation='vertical',)
        self.but = Button(text= 'hola')
        self.bx.add_widget(self.but)
        self.bx.bind(minimum_height=self.bx.setter("height"))
        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(100)]



class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The class `RecycleView` uses the attribute `viewclass` as data container, so you have to use `self.viewclass = Button` here.

```py
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bx = RecycleBoxLayout(
            default_size=(None, dp(56)),
            default_size_hint=(1, None),
            size_hint=(1, None),
            orientation='vertical',
        )
        self.bx.bind(minimum_height=self.bx.setter("height"))
        self.add_widget(self.bx)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.update_view)
        
    def update_view(self, *args):
        #Items that will be used as data-container.
        self.viewclass = Button # Or, "Button"
        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(100)]
```

Also note that you've to schedule the data updation in order to get the view. Alternatively, you can define (almost) everything in kivy-lang without the need of scheduling. You can find an example in [Kivy documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html).